# Why ordering of rows in a sql table changes automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am creating a table `T1` in sql ordered by dates descending.
But when I `SELECT * FROM T1`, then the order changes.

PS: This didn't happen when I was working in SQL Server 2008 but now I am working on SQL Express 2012 and it's creating problems.

Comment: There is no inherent table order. The order of rows returned by a SQL query is only governed by the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Here is the [**"established" article**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx) on this topic..

Answer (score 0):

generally this changes should not effect by changing a version. Could you please check your Table level Index as well.

Thanks
NAdir